# How to dynamically change content in HTML based on php database values?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I have this web based app with PHP (mysql) backend. I have a page to enter the grades and position received in a particular event. I need the page to show the checkboxes (for the grades) only if they have not been entered before. So I have this column P1 in my database and if this is NULL i need to show the checkboxes.

This is what i have on the php side

```
<?php
$PID = (int)$_GET['PID'];
$con = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password",'events');
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM eventlist WHERE Eid=$PID");
global $output;
$row =  $result->fetch_assoc();
echo '<h1>'.$row["Ename"].'</h1>';
if($row["P1"]==NULL)
?>
```

and what i need to be displayed in P1 is NULL is as follows

```
<h2>Slot 1</h2>
<h3>Enter Result</h3>
<div id="c1" class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt1radio" value=30>First</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt1radio" value=20>Second</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt1radio" value=10>Third</label>
</div>
<h3>Enter Grade</h3>
<div id="c2" class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=5>A</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=4>B</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=3>C</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=2>D</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=0>DQ</label>
</div>
<div id="submit">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>
```

How can i do this without putting echo in each and every HTML line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. If you don't want to use `echo`, just enclose the `html` in the `if` without including the `html` in the `php` area

```
<?php
 $PID = (int)$_GET['PID'];
    $con = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password",'events');
    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM eventlist WHERE Eid=$PID");
    global $output;
    $row =  $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo '<h1>'.$row["Ename"].'</h1>';
    if($row["P1"]==NULL){
  ?>

<h2>Slot 1</h2>
    <h3>Enter Result</h3>
    <div id="c1" class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="opt1radio" value=30>First</label>

      <label><input type="radio" name="opt1radio" value=20>Second</label>

      <label><input type="radio" name="opt1radio" value=10>Third</label>
    </div>

   <h3>Enter Grade</h3>  
   <div id="c2" class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=5>A</label>

      <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=4>B</label>

      <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=3>C</label>

      <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=2>D</label>

       <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=0>DQ</label>
    </div>
    <div id="submit">

      <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked so that others may know what is working for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only think that you are missing is to retrieve all rows one by one, you can do it with: `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` and then put all your code like:

```
<?php
 $PID = (int)$_GET['PID'];
    $con = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password",'events');
    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM eventlist WHERE Eid=$PID");
    global $output;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<h1>'.$row["Ename"].'</h1>';
    if($row["P1"]==NULL){
  ?>

<h2>Slot 1</h2>
    <h3>Enter Result</h3>
    <div id="c1" class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="opt1radio" value=30>First</label>

      <label><input type="radio" name="opt1radio" value=20>Second</label>

      <label><input type="radio" name="opt1radio" value=10>Third</label>
    </div>

   <h3>Enter Grade</h3>  
   <div id="c2" class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=5>A</label>

      <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=4>B</label>

      <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=3>C</label>

      <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=2>D</label>

       <label><input type="radio" name="opt2radio" value=0>DQ</label>
    </div>
    <div id="submit">

      <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
<?php } }?>
```

Whitout the while, your code only will show the first result.

Hope it helps!